# numpy freezes at specific functions or array masked assignment

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, freeze

!!! For everything following, the numpy version used is 1.21.0

I am currently working on some open source code that has to do with gene information, when I tried to run it for the first time, it stalled doing nothing in the first steps, after some investigations I found that the problem came from the following piece of code (in my case allele_matrix is a numpy array of shape (1024,1,2) with dtype being np.int8 )

```py
dot_mask = allele_matrix == -1
    
if np.any(dot_mask):
    missing_rep_val = np.max(allele_matrix) + 1
    allele_matrix[dot_mask] = missing_rep_val # This line runs forever
else:
    missing_rep_val = None
```

Since this project is compiled a bit strangely, I thought it had something to do with it and decided to extract the array `allele_matrix` (using `np.save`) and try the exact same operation in a very simple python script, but the same problem appeared:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.load("allele_mat.debug.npy")
a[a == -1] = 2 # Same problem here
```

I then thought it had perhaps something to do with strange values inside the array, but when I tried using `np.unique` to find the values in the array, the code also froze.

```py
np.unique(a) # Also runs forever
```

I am able to do the above operations manually using loops and iterating over the array: **It works**. By using this, I found that the values in this array are limited to just {-1,0,1}

```py
# This works as expected and gives {-1,0,1}
import numpy as np
a = np.load("allele_mat.debug.npy")
vals = set()
for i in range(1024):
    for j in range(1):
        for k in range(2):
            vals.add(a[i][j][k])
print(vals)
```

This is not a performance problem, as there are only 2048 elements it should be pretty much instantaneous. Also, I thought it might be my numpy installation that was broken but trying on very small, hand crafted arrays (e.g. `[[[-1,0]], [[0,1]]]`, even setting dtype as np.int8 aswell), the mask assignment works fine. Also, for any of these execution, the memory usage stays below 50MB, and my machine has 16GB of ram.

This freezing problem appears at multiple places in the code, and so switching all of them to loop-alternatives is not really feasible.

You can download the file I used for all my tests by running the following command (first time I use this hosting service, I have no idea how long the link will be valid)

```bash
curl -X GET https://basedbin.fly.dev/LGZ0FI.debug --output mat.npy
```

If anyone has any idea what could be happening, it would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't quite understand why this happens, I found out that my python version seems to be the culprit. I switched from version 3.10 to 3.8 and everything now works as expected!